# If one circuit is on, turn another off

Tags: circuit-design

Noob question I'm sure, but I wonder if there's a simple device that will switch off current on one circuit when it senses current on another.

I'm replacing OEM switches in my car. Subaru's design is to power a backlight continuously, and power another light if the system is on. For example, the 'cruise' button backlight is on continuously, and the cruise computer powers a separate light if the system is turned on. The billet buttons I'm looking at have RGB backlighting with a common wire, i.e. four total leads to power the backlight. I'd like to connect the red lead to the continuous backlight power and the green lead to the system-activated power. However the product of this will be red/yellow instead of red/green as far as I understand it. (This is written as 'system-off-color'/'system-on-color'.) I would like to add some relay-like component to the circuit such that when the system-on light is powered, the continuous backlight circuit will open, resulting in red/green.

Comment: No, not a simple device.

Comment: Oh bummer. I thought for sure it'd just be a gap in my knowledge

Comment: Question is, what is the device that would allow the switching described

Comment: I feel like what I'm describing is the normally-closed side of a relay, but I don't need any high current capability. Maybe a low current relay if such a thing exists?

Comment: Sorry, but this is *unanswerable* without the details of the lighting circuit.   Even assuming these are LED's we'd have to know which side of the LED is driven to even begin to suggest a solution; and it might not just be one LED, but a series string with a CC driver and potentially booster. Questions on the *modification* of *undocumented* products are not on topic; if you can determine the circuity of what you want to interface to and edit that into the question, re-opening might be possible.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Fair enough. Looks from the conversation that the idea is not as simple as I had imagined, so I'll just solve it a different way. Thanks for the input!